# like a post using facebook api open graph

Tags: php, facebook

I am using php script for liking a post externally through `open graph` and `facebook API`

```
$response = $facebook->api('/me/og.likes','POST',array('object' => ""));
```

in my above code what i have to write in object so that my post will be liked .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the URL of the object in the double quotes like so:

```
$response = $facebook->api( '/me/og.likes', 'POST', array( 'object' => "http://www.example.com/foo" ) );
```

But for this to work you must make sure that the document you are linking to has opengraph metadata. [Check the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/).

Comment: thank you but i want to know that <meta property="fb:app_id" content="121323231434234" /> 
          <meta property="og:type"   content="object" /> 
          <meta property="og:url"    content="http://www.example.com/foo" /> 
          <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Object" /> 
          <meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> this is the correct method